# How to find specific kindle highlights using Regex

Tags: regex

Kindle saves all highlights and notes from all books in a single txt file. I want to find (filter) notes from specific book.

Each highlight starts with a line with the name of the book and author. Like:
`Letter from an Unknown Woman (Stefan Zweig)`

Then goes some multi-line text

Each highlight ends with a character line:
`==========`

I want to find (and replace with nothing) all highlights, that don't start with a line `Letter from an Unknown Woman (Stefan Zweig)`, and
don't find (keep) all highlights, that starts with a line `Letter from an Unknown Woman (Stefan Zweig)` and ends with `==========`

I tried `[^Letter from an Unknown Woman (Stefan Zweig).*==========].*`, but it doesn't work.

I'm new to regex and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Find all notes that starts with a title and author and rebuild your file with the matches.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the configuration of what you use to use regex works, but check if using this regex works

```
Letter from an Unknown Woman \(Stefan Zweig\).*?(={10}\n|$)
```